# SQL SUM - GROUP BY - DATETIME

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sum

Im looking for a solution for an SQL query which can group values by NR, SUM by VALUE but keep only the dates where the VALUE is positive. (with the same NR only 1 positive can be, the rest are negative).

[image: SQL DATA HERE]

```
SELECT
  NR,
  SUM(VALUE),
  DATE (MUST BE THE DATE WHERE VALUE IS POSITIVE)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY NR
```

Expected Result

[image: Expected Result]

If someone has a solution for this, please help. Thank you.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What about this one: `SELECT NR, SUM(VALUE) AS SumOfValue, MAX([Date]) FROM Table GROUP BY Nr` ?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you well...

```
SELECT A.NR, SUM(A.VALUE) AS [Value], B.[Date]
FROM YourTable A INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT Nr, MAX([Date]) As [Date]
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE [Value]>-1
    GROUP BY Nr
) B ON A.Nr = B.Nr
GROUP BY A.Nr, B.[Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be it

```
SELECT
  NR,
  SUM(VALUE),
  CASE
    WHEN VALUE > 0 THEN DATE
    ELSE ''
  END
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY VALUE DESC
)
GROUP BY NR
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is simply returning the maximum date for the positive values.  That is a simple aggregation query:

```
select nr, sum(value), max(date)
from t
group by nr
having sum(value) > 0;
```

However, the description suggests a cumulative sum, like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(value) over (order by date) as running_value
      from t
     ) t
where running_value > 0;
```

This happens to return the same results for the data in your question.  However, this seems to be what you are asking for.